# Adding 'tfoot' Prevents Cumulative_Filtering from Working

Tags: datatables, datatables-1.10, yadcf

I would like to use cumulative_filtering and to have the filters display in the footer, not the header. Both of these features are working on their own, but when I include both options together the cumulative_filtering does not work (the tfoot option is still working). How can I use these two options together? Thanks!

```
yadcf.init(table, [
    { column_number: 1, filter_reset_button_text: false, select_type: 'select2' },
    { column_number: 2, filter_reset_button_text: false, select_type: 'select2' },
    { column_number: 3, filter_reset_button_text: false, select_type: 'select2' },
    { column_number: 4, filter_reset_button_text: false, select_type: 'select2' },
    { column_number: 6, filter_reset_button_text: false, select_type: 'select2' },
    { column_number: 7, filter_reset_button_text: false, select_type: 'select2' },
    { column_number: 8, filter_reset_button_text: false, select_type: 'select2', column_data_type: "html", html_data_type: "text" }
    ],
    'footer',
    { cumulative_filtering: true }
)
```

Cumulative Filtering: http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/cumulative_filtering.html

Per the documentation - "Filters can be placed in the header (thead) or in the footer (tfoot) , second argument of yadcf constructor or third argument of init function"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs are a bit unclear (will update them soon about this feature),
Anyway since you want to specify the filters location and use the cumulative you should use it in the following way

```
yadcf.init(table, [
    { column_number: 1, filter_reset_button_text: false, select_type: 'select2' },
    { column_number: 2, filter_reset_button_text: false, select_type: 'select2' },
    { column_number: 3, filter_reset_button_text: false, select_type: 'select2' },
    { column_number: 4, filter_reset_button_text: false, select_type: 'select2' },
    { column_number: 6, filter_reset_button_text: false, select_type: 'select2' },
    { column_number: 7, filter_reset_button_text: false, select_type: 'select2' },
    { column_number: 8, filter_reset_button_text: false, select_type: 'select2', column_data_type: "html", html_data_type: "text" }
    ],
    {
        filters_position: 'footer',
        cumulative_filtering: true 
    }
)
```

Its either the third argument as a string (for position) or third argument for an object with `filters_position` key and 'footer' as a value.